# cors in akka http with headerValueByName issue (akka-http-cors)

Tags: scala, cors, akka, akka-http

I'm trying to add CORS support for my akka http API while using `akka-http-cors`: https://github.com/lomigmegard/akka-http-cors

Everything is working fine when I'm basically adding cors support to a *simple* route, for instance:

```scala
val route = cors() {
    path("ping") {
       get {
           complete("pong")
       }
    }
}
```

with the corresponding jQuery call:

```js
$.ajax({
     url: "http://localhost:9000/ping",
     type: "GET",
     success: function(data) { alert(data); }
  });
```

returns properly **"pong"** as expected

---

But when I try to extract (server side) some particular header from the request, the cors support for the response seems to be suddenly broken. For instance, with:

```scala
val route = cors() {
    headerValueByName("myheader") { (myheader) =>
       path("ping") {
           get {
               complete("pong")
           }
       }
    }
}
```

with the corresponding jQuery call:

```js
$.ajax({
     url: "http://localhost:9000/ping",
     type: "GET",
     beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('myheader', 'test');},
     success: function(data) { alert('Success!' + data); }
  });
```

fails with cors error in console:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:9000/ping. 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access. 
The response had HTTP status code 400.
```

It seems that adding **headerValueByName(...)** to the route breaks cors support and I can't figure out why.

I've also tried different implementations of cors (based on custom traits) and the behavior is the same with all of them.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please debug your server route with a tool like `curl` to see the actual response from the server, not the JavaScript's interpretation.

```
curl -X GET -H "Origin: http://example.com" -H "myheader: test" http://localhost:9000/ping
```

I suspect that your custom header is not properly sent in the HTTP request. The `headerValueByName` directive will then reject the request. The rejection bubbles up (skipping the `cors` directive) to be finally handled by the default rejection handler. The CORS-related headers are therefore not responded.

You should have your rejection and exception handlers **inside** the `cors` directive, not outside (like with the default ones). Please look at the following example.

```
def route: Route = {
  import CorsDirectives._
  import Directives._

  // Your CORS settings
  val corsSettings = CorsSettings.defaultSettings

  // Your rejection handler
  val rejectionHandler = corsRejectionHandler withFallback RejectionHandler.default

  // Your exception handler
  val exceptionHandler = ExceptionHandler {
    ...
  }

  // Combining the two handlers only for convenience
  val handleErrors = handleRejections(rejectionHandler) & handleExceptions(exceptionHandler)

  // Note how rejections and exceptions are handled *before* the CORS directive (in the inner route).
  // This is required to have the correct CORS headers in the response even when an error occurs.
  handleErrors {
    cors(corsSettings) {
      handleErrors {
        ... // your business route here
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This will not solve your header issue, but at least the CORS headers will be part of the HTTP response even when the route is rejected or fails with an exception.